# Phpmyadmin Export/Import issue with line breaks

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, export

I try to export a wordpress database from my old host via phpmyadmin.
I leave all settings on default and in the sql file, all new lines are seperated by "\n" command  (or "\n" or "\n\n")

Then i import this sql file into my new server via phpmyadmin, but now in phpmyadmin the line breaks are not invisible, but u can see alot of "\n" and "\n\n"

In the old phpmyadmin i couldnt see those "\n", instead there were real line breaks.
And when looking at the page via browser, its even worse. Theres not only "\n" but also "\r\n"

Any ideas please, what could be the problem?! (both are utf8)

**edit:**

i am sure it is more an export then an import problem, because another database i imported earlier from another host, worked fine and those "\n"'s work, but i have no idea why this 1 backup is broken

Comment: that because of diffrence of windows and *unix systems, windows use "\r\n" and *unix use "\n"

Comment: wow ok thanks, that makes sense. it's possible that this one host was on windows. let me google for a solution then :) thanks

Comment: It may be an issue with escape sequences. `\n` stands for line feed, but if the `\` character itself is escaped again, then `\\n` will be displayed as the string `'\n'`.

Comment: is it actually safe to just rewrite all "\\r\\n" to "\\n\\n" in my backup.sql, before importing on my *unix system? and can there be any more problems because of the earlier windows host?

Comment: can't edit my above comment anymore but the way i fixed it was by replacing all "\\r\\n" with "" (nothing). but could be problem with this specific host also. there's a reason i left it :)

Answer (score 8):

Which phpMyAdmin version are you using on each system? There is a [bug with version 4.6.5.1](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12765) that causes this issue on export. phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2 has been released to address this, or you can [use this patch](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/e61b2135da52051bb158c37b9eed35d734bf441c.patch) if you desire.

*Edited to include the news that 4.6.5.2 has been released*

Comment: Thank you, was just wondering why this started happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

As Issac said, it seems to be a bug with phpmyAdmin version 4.6.5.1 who generates this problem.
In my case, I have searched thru all the .sql file for this 3 strings:

```
\\r\\n
\\n
\\r
```

And replaced them with a space. Everything works perfectly again.