# MySQL export adds carriage formatting

Tags: phpmyadmin

This never happend before, but when I export a (WordPress) database from my live webserver, it adds `\\r\\n`s everywhere! I don't know why and I would very much like to know how to prevent it.

I'm using phpMyAdmin for import/export.

Comment: Could you use `mysqldump` in the meantime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phpmyadmin Export/Import issue with line breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911643/phpmyadmin-export-import-issue-with-line-breaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by PMA in versions < 4.6.5.2 and has nothing to do with WP. Was fixed in the latest version (4.6.5.2) according to changelog:

> Welcome to phpMyAdmin version 4.6.5.2, a patch-level release which fixes an issue with exporting certain character sequences including a backslash (), such as \r\n.
>
> Because this issue [#12765](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12765) affects export functionality, we do recommend updating when possible.

If you're hosting with WPEngine (just a hunch :P) it might be a good idea to let them know.

Comment: Thankyou!! Phpmyadmin is recently updated, and currently running 4.6.5.1 so I'm gonna contact my sysadmin to upgrade to 4.6.5.2 asap!