# phpMyAdmin export results in Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am migrating a database from another server and using phpMyAdmin to generate a sql dump.  The issue comes up on a `text` column insert where apparently the exported data is just slightly too long.  I understand how to turn off STRICT mode but this only results in the inserted data getting truncated which is not what I want.  I don't see how it's possible that the exported data is too long to insert again unless phpMyAdmin is somehow adding characters to the field.

The max length of a `text` field is 65,535 and what I'm inserting turns out to be only a few hundred characters too long.  As a workaround I am going to change the insert statement to create the field as `longtext` but I'd really like to knkow why my export is not importable as is and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here.  Apparently phpMyadmin exports newlines as `\r\n`.  I did a bit of reading about this being a [bug in some versions of 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911643/phpmyadmin-export-import-issue-with-line-breaks) - however I'm using v4.7 and it's still exhibiting this behavior.  Long story short, a simple newline becomes **4 characters** - so on a `text` field that is exactly 65,535 charactesr (probably truncated in the past), the exported data is now longer than what's actually there in the table.

For me the fix was to open the file in vim and do a simple:

```
:%s#\\r\\n#\r#g
```

Which replaces all those characters with actual newlines.